# Create vector with 0 or 1 elements from an Option

Tags: rust

Is there a shorter and simpler way to achieve this:

```
let o: Option<i32> = ...;
let ve: Vec<i32> = match o {
    None => vec![],
    Some(n) => vec![n],
};
```

Comment: `o.map(|e| vec![e]).unwrap_or_default()`  can be used as an alternative

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Option` implements `IntoIterator`, so you can make an iterator and collect it:

```
let ve: Vec<i32> = o.into_iter().collect();
```

Comment: Nice. I didn't know `Option` is iterable. That can be very convenient. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

```rust
let o: Option<i32> = Some(2);
let ve: Vec<i32> = o.into_iter().collect();
```

[Playground Link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=bb2f433333ccd8f93abd809056a728ca)